# including LT SPICE model through lt spice folder directory

Tags: ltspice

I would like to include a model. It involves creating the SPICE model in the LT SPICE "sub" directory, as is shown in the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8V5XabccFaE&list=PLT84nve2j1g_wgGcm0Bv3K4RSl2Jdjsey&index=4

in minute 7 second 16

the problem I am encountering is

I can't change the file extension type like is done in the video. When I try to change the type, it ends up being _.lib.txt instead of _.lib. How can I get around this? Ultimately I want to include the file into the schematic with the command ".inc _.lib"

The option to add a file is not showing up.

[image]

edit1: I figured it out. I saved it as _.txt in USERS>myusername>Documents>LTSPICEXVII>lib>sub as _.txt and then in LT SPICE, I went into .op, clicked SPICE directive, and typed in ".inc _.txt" . It worked. Changing the file extension to .lib ended up not being necessary.

Comment: This appears to be more of a Windows issue than an LTSpice issue. I would try using CMD and utilizing the `ren` command along with its arguments.

Comment: In addition to your solution (which is odd, but who can argue with success?), if you use Notepad on Windows then it will insist on the .TXT extension, unless you over-ride it using a drop-down on the File/Save dialog. That could be one problem. But even if that's a problem, you can always just use Windows file manager and change the extension by renaming the file. These are all basic skills to have.

Comment: In Notepad (and some other text editors) when you save the file in the Save dialog change 'Save as Type' to 'All Files (*,*)', then it will use the extension you provide, otherwise it will add .txt to whatever you put.